# creating a win/loss recording method between 2 different teams

Tags: java

How do I create a method that records the wins / losses between 2 different teams?
Here is the team object & constructors.

```
public class NFLTeam4
{   private int win;
    private int loss;
    private String team;

public NFLTeam4(String teamName)
{   win = 0;
    loss = 0;
    team = teamName;
}
public NFLTeam4(int w, int l)
{   win = w;
    loss = l;
}
}
```

This is my attempt to create a win a game method.

```
public class NFLGameDay4{
   public static void main(String[] args){  
    NFLTeam4 falcons = new NFLTeam4("Falcons");
    NFLTeam4 chiefs = new NFLTeam4("Chiefs");
    NFLTeam4 jets = new NFLTeam4("Jets");
}       

public NFLTeam4 winAGame(NFLTeam4 b)
{   int win = 1;
    int loss = 0;
    return new NFLTeam4(win, loss);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks like your `NFLTeam4` class is capable of representing a team...

```
public NFLTeam4(String teamName) {   
    win = 0;
    loss = 0;
    team = teamName;
}
```

... or a team's record ...

```
public NFLTeam4(int w, int l) {   
    win = w;
    loss = l;
}
```

but not both: there's no way to provide a team name up-front and then modify the record later. To correct that (and thereby make managing a team's record possible), consider removing the second constructor (the `int w, int l` one) and creating two methods to handle changing the record for you:

```
public void addWin() { 
    ++win;
}

//similar code for addLoss
```

Note you'll probably want to add methods like `getWinCount` and the like. What you want to add and how you code it is up to you, this is just to get you started.

Now `winAGame` only needs to call `addWin` on the team that was provided (`NFLTeam4 b`).

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. In the winAGame method, how should I account for one team's win count to go up and the other team's lose count to go down?

So if I'm using Falcons.winAGame(Jets) how can I record a win for the Falcons and a loss for the Jets?

Comment: @dk1 Right now `winAGame` is a member of `NFLGameDay4` and it only takes 1 team. So you could change it to take two teams, `a` and `b`, and have `a` get the win and `b` get the loss. You'd call it from `main` like `winAGame(falcons, jets)` once you have it take two teams.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a results `Map` within the `NFLTeam4` class.

```
public class NFLTeam4
{
  private enum RESULT { WIN, LOSS };
  private Map<RESULT, List<NFLTeam4>> results = new HashMap<RESULT, ArrayList<NFLTeam4>>;
  // you can leave the constructor and other variables as they are

  public void winAGame(NFLTeam4 b) {
    win = win + 1;
    // Now check and add to your results map 
    // you will need to make sure your map is initialised properly
    results.get(RESULT.WIN).add(b);
  }
}
```

You are encapsulating the behavior of winning or losing a game in your NFLTeam4 object. You could also extend the `RESULT` enum to include some information on the date, game number, venue, etc. of the result.

This is just an illustration on how this could work. You should consider how your objects are designed in light of the requirements.